# Rails FAILS on Xcode 5 and Mavericks

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For the past couple of days I have been trying to install rails on my machine which has Mavericks.

Whenever I run `sudo gem install rails` I get the following:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
make: *** No rule to make target `/include/universal-darwin13/ruby/config.h', needed by `atomic_reference.o'.  Stop.
```

I have **already** installed the Xcode tools using xcode-select --install. I am using Xcode 5. Installing the tool has no effect and I get the same error all the time.

Comment: This could be helpful: http://dean.io/setting-up-a-ruby-on-rails-development-environment-on-mavericks/

Answer (score 0):

Use ruby version manager (https://rvm.io/) and do not install gems system wide.